# Картинка на уровне со списком

Tags: html, css

Добрый день. 
Мне нужно сдвинуть список на уровень картинки, справа от неё. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал "display: inline-block" картинки, списка, блока - не помогает. 
Возможно, что-то делаю не так?

Код:

```
        <div>
            <img src = "https://pp.vk.me/c836231/v836231177/241f/1Zn_pgeYQAI.jpg" width = "400px">      
            <ul class="border">
              <li>Meow</li>
              <li>Meow</li>
              <li>Meow</li>
              <li>Meow</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нужно поставить и кртинке и блоку "display: inline-block",  а блоку списком задать ширину

```
<div>
            <img src = "https://pp.vk.me/c836231/v836231177/241f/1Zn_pgeYQAI.jpg" width = "400px;" style="display:inline-block;">      
            <ul class="border" style="width:400px;display:inline-block;">
              <li>Meow</li>
              <li>Meow</li>
              <li>Meow</li>
              <li>Meow</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: О, спасибо :)
Я делал display inline-block и список, и картинку, и ограничивал в размере саму картинку, а вот со списком не догадался размеры выставить.

Comment: не за что =) можно было сделать еще как варинат для картинки float:left; и для списка будет по идее тоже самое